# SQL: How can I determine quickly whether a string (sentence) includes words from my sql database?

Tags: php, sql

I have a question/problem. How can I determine quickly whether a string (sentence) includes words from my sql database? In PHP I use following code:

```
if(strpos($string,"abc")!==false) { 
    //abc is in $string 
} else {
    //abc isn't in $string 
}
```

Example:

Sql-Database: words -> my garden, sun, water

String: My garden is green.

Has someone suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the alternative of strpos?

Comment: You mean a query to do that? Because you can do it with strpos after obteining the words from the db.

Comment: 'My garden is green' is a random example. I need a sql statement which checks if a given string (mostly sentences) contains words from my database. @Elanochecer yes.

Comment: Should it be case-sensitive?

Comment: @Qirel: Yes please.

Comment: Just use like. For further explanation we need the db structure.

Comment: You can query the database using like field = "%garden%"

Comment: DB structure: table-name: 'woerter' ; column-name: 'inhalt'. @Elanochecer: But when I compare random sentences with a list of words from column 'inhalt', it works too? Like the example in my main post. Because I have over 1000 sentences which should be checked if certain words (the words from the column 'inhalt') are in them.

Comment: What database engine do you use? Is it MySQL?

Comment: @Joni: Yes. I use MySQL.

Comment: You can start with `where instr('my garden is green', inhalt)` but if you have a lot of words and long sentences it's going to be slow, and also it will match partial words (sentence "water" will match word "ate"). Does that work for you?

Comment: @Joni: Thank you for your answer. But instr is case-insensitive. Have you a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  some_table
WHERE
  'My garden is green' LIKE BINARY CONCAT('%', some_column, '%')
```

Comment: Thank you! But this isn't case-sensitive. Have you a solution for this?

Comment: Yes!
I updated the query from LIKE to LIKE BINARY which is case sensitive like you want.
BINARY means it is comparing the binary values of each character, rather than the letters they represent. In non-binary comparison "A" = "a", where as in binary comparison "A" != "a" because 65 != 97.

Answer (score 0):

so let's assume that you fetched the data from the database using a while loop

```
 $senetence = "The man's garden was green";
 $wanted_words = 'garden'; 
 if($wanted_word = stripos($senetence, $wanted_words))
 {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($wanted_words .": is at position ". $wanted_word ." from ". $senetence);
    echo "</pre>";
    return false;
 }
 else
 {
    return true;
 }
```